# How can one remove a branch from a project on GitHub?

Tags: github

How can I remove a branch from a GitHub project? 
I do not want this branch to be visible.

https://zapodaj.net/dcd93bda502d8.png.html

Comment: `git push origin --delete the_remote_branch`

Comment: You can't remove the master branch...

Answer (score 0):

You must always have at least one active branch. If you want to remove `master` (not recommended) create a new branch, change your default branch to the new one, then delete master.